# VSCode Issue: Vue example doesn't work in Firefox / Chrome, but it works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, firefox, visual-studio-code

When I run the below code in Firefox or Chrome it gives me the following result:

```
{‌{ value }}
{‌{ value }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
{‌{ element }}
```

Here is the actual code, when I run it in jsfiddle or stack overflow, it works just fine:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    testData: {
      name: 'TESTOBJECT', 
      id: 10,
      data: [1.67, 1.33, 0.98, 2.21]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="value in testData">
      <template v-if="Array.isArray(value)">
        <div v-for="element in value">{{ element }}</div>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        {{ value }}
      </template>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What error are you getting in local ? can  you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: perhaps you're *doing something wrong™* in the *actual* code you are serving - any errors in the browsers developer tools console? that's step 1 in debugging your code

Comment: I run the `new Vue` instance inside `app.js` and attach the file to the html file at the end of `</body>` as `<script src="app.js">`. Other code inside the same file works fine, also the same code works fine if I do NOT nest `v-if` inside `v-for` There are no errors in the browser console and Vue devtools is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `VSCode` issue. It does not show all characters, but stores them anyway. So it showed me the following:

`{{ value }}`

But what actually was saved inside the file and also processed by the browser was this:

[image]

To prevent this error, you can install the following VSCode extension: [Highlight Bad Chars](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wengerk.highlight-bad-chars)

Answer (score 0):

Usually doing this as simple importing vuejs, taking your code, it works:

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="value in testData">
                <template v-if="Array.isArray(value)">
                    <div v-for="element in value">{{ element }}</div>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    {{ value }}
                </template>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    testData: {
      name: "TESTOBJECT",
      id: 10,
      data: [1.67, 1.33, 0.98, 2.21]
    }
  }
});
```